# Simple 2-d recurrence solution in terms of binomial coefficients - how to prove?

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

In the solution to the post here: [Number of $h$ hop paths between two vertices with shortest path $s$ on an $n$ sided polygon.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709168/number-of-h-hop-paths-between-two-vertices-with-shortest-path-s-on-an-n-si#3709193), @hdighfan mentions the following recurrence and its solution.

$$
f(s, h) =
\begin{cases}
1 & h = 0, s = 0 \\
0 & h = 0, s \neq 0 \\
f(s+1, h-1) + f(s-1, h-1) & h > 0.
\end{cases}
$$
This recurrence has solution
$$
f(s, h) = \begin{cases}
\binom{h}{(h+s)/2} & h = s \bmod{2} \\
0 & h \neq s \bmod{2},
\end{cases}
$$
where $\binom{n}{r}$ is defined to be $0$ for $r < 0$ or $r > n$.

I'm still lost as to how one would go about deriving the solution for a two-dimensional recurrence like this?

Comment: For this particular two-dimensional recurrence, the method was undoubtedly to recognize that it was the Pascal's triangle recurrence, indexed in a slightly unusual way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found in terms of generating functions. We have:

$$f(s,h)=f(h-1,s)+f(h-1,s-1)$$

Let's define the generating function:

$$F_h(x) = \sum\limits_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}f(h,s)x^s$$
$$=\sum\limits_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}(f(h-1,s)+f(h-1,s-1))x^s$$
$$=\frac{F_{h-1}(x)}{x}+xF_{h-1}(x)$$
$$F_h(x)=\frac{(1+x^2)}{x}F_{h-1}(x)$$

Now from the base case, we get: $F_0(x)=1$

So we get:

$$F_h(x)=\left(\frac{1+x^2}{x}\right)^h=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{h}{h \choose k}x^{2k-h}$$

Let $2k-h=s$. This gives us: $k=\frac{h+s}{2}$

Meaning:

$$F_h(x) = \sum\limits_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}{h \choose \frac{h+s}{2}}x^s$$

And the result follows. This method can be used also to prove the Pascal triangle recurrence has binomial terms as solution. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3718655/155881